# System.Windows.Forms.Control not contain "GetEnumerator" public definition?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

When I want to traverse a Forms control, this `foreach` statement (`foreach (Control __control in _control)`) gives an error:

> System.Windows.Forms.Control not contain "GetEnumerator" public
>   definition.So foreach statement can't be
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control' types variable.

Here is my code:

```
public DataTable addFormControlName(DataTable dt, string[] controls)
        {
            foreach (string controlName in controls)
            {                
                foreach (Control _control in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (_control.Name.ToString() == controlName)
                    {
                        if (_control.HasChildren)
                        {
                            foreach (Control __control in _control)
                            {
                                //traverse the control like 'groupBox'...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

What could I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to enumerate some (collection) object in `foreach` loop, that object should implement [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. `Control` do not implement this interface. Thus you have error here:

```
foreach (Control __control in _control)
```

If you want to enumerate children of your `_control` you should enumerate over its `Controls` collection:

```
foreach (Control __control in _control.Controls)
```

Also consider to use LINQ for getting your controls by names:

```
var controlsToUse = Controls.Cast<Control>()
                            .Where(c => controls.Contains(c.Name));
// do what you want
```

Comment: And how could i do? I implement the IEnumerable?But in other case i am used to do but no error.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but does it not require a method called `GetEnumerator` which can exist without implementing the interface?

Comment: @DavidPilkington yes, exactly - you need interface to be implemented. Simple `GetEnumerator` method will not make your object enumerable